# Expand div and background with dropdown list box navigation

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a menu that is at the top of a page.  The background of the div is black with a 50% opacity.  When you mouseover the list it fires a drop down sub menu.  The sub menu is run by a hover function that fades it in.  I would like to expand the background of the div to when the sub menu appears so that it slides down with the submenu, I know I could just give the submenu a background, but I want the background of the div to expand so that it fills the page, to the amount that the submenu takes up, but goes back after you leave the hover.

Here is my function for the submenu hover.  I am thinking something could be added to this to change the style on the div.

```
$('.nav li, .subTopMenu li').hover(
    // When mouse enters the .navigation element
    function () {
        //Fade in the navigation submenu
        $('ul', this).fadeIn();     // fadeIn will show the sub cat menu
    },
    // When mouse leaves the .navigation element
    function () {
        //Fade out the navigation submenu
        $('ul', this).fadeOut();     // fadeOut will hide the sub cat menu
    }

);
```

The div and list are html like so;

```
<div class="topMenu">
<a href="#"><img      src="images/logo-small.png"></a>
<ul class="subTopMenu">
<li class="noHover"><a href="#">Link1</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#" id="navclick" data-iclick="tAbout">ABOUT US</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="navclick" data-iclick="tHistory" data-bgsrc="images/history.jpg">HISTORY</a></li>
<li><a href="#">OUR BOARD</a></li>
<li><a href="#">CONTRIBUTE</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="noHover"><a href="#">Link2</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">SHOP</a></li>
<li><a href="#">EAT</a></li>
<li><a href="#">DRINK</a></li>
<li><a href="#">JOIN</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="noHover"><a href="#">Link3</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">MUSIC</a></li>
<li><a href="#">ART</a></li>
<li><a href="#">FESTIVALS</a></li>
<li><a href="#">LECTURES</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="noHover"><a href="#">Link4</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">WHEN & WHERE</a></li>
<li><a href="#">REGISTER</a></li>
<li><a href="#">VOLUNTEER</a></li>
<li><a href="#">SPONSOR</a></li>
<li><a href="#">GALLERY</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

The div is styled in css;

```
.topMenu
{
 display:none;
 top:0px;
 position:relative;
 padding:10px;
 background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 text-align:center;
}
.topMenu li
{
display:inline;
position:relative;
text-align:center;
}
```

I was thinking something like this using the jqueryUi effect to resize the div, but it doesn't seem to cut it.  The div animates to height, but it keeps going back and forth between the 2 heights.

```
    $('.noHover').mouseover(
    function () {
        //Increase the size of the topMenu div
            $('.topMenu').animate({height: '200'},'slow');
            });
    $('.subTopMenu').mouseout(
            function(){
                    $('.topMenu').animate({height: '90'},'slow');
            });
        $('.nav li, .subTopMenu li').hover(
    // When mouse enters the .navigation element
    function () {
        //Fade in the navigation submenu
        $('ul', this).fadeIn();     // fadeIn will show the sub cat menu
            },
    // When mouse leaves the .navigation element
    function () {
        //Fade out the navigation submenu
        $('ul', this).fadeOut();     // fadeOut will hide the sub cat menu
                    }

);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution, not exactly what I wanted as I was hoping for a nicely eased or animated slide, but this does the trick

```
    $('.noHover').mouseover(
function () {
  var navht = $(this).attr('data-navht');
    //Increase the size of the topMenu div
        $('.topMenu').css('height', navht);
        });
$('.subTopMenu').mouseout(
function(){
  $('.topMenu').css("height", "90px");
});
```

I also added an attribute of data-navht so I could set the height depending on the total amount of children in the submenu so the div extends to the bottom.